# Collection "@schematics/angular" cannot be resolved

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I just installed angular cli in my ubuntu, but when I try to create new app by 
`ng new my-dream-app` It shows error saying `Collection "@schematics/angular" cannot be resolved.
Error: Collection "@schematics/angular" cannot be resolved.` I installed **@schematics/angular** by `npm install @schematics/angular` but it didnt work. I uninstalled angular cli and again reinstalled it but it didnt work, it throws same error.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed angular-cli with -g key, it should be fine. If not, try installing angular-cli globally.
Then you could check dependencies. In your node_modules find @angular folder. There inside /cli/node_modules you should see @schematics folder. If it exists, everything should be fine.