# Collection "@candiman/website" cannot be resolved

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I have checked [Collection “@schematics/angular” cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938225/collection-schematics-angular-cannot-be-resolved)
 and it's not duplicate.

I have created my own schematics and when I try to use it using `ng add @candiman/website@0.0.5-beta.3` I am getting below errors.

I think the problem is `collection.json` not packaged and shipped to the `npm package` as `ng-packgr` does not include `JSON` files

So, physical `collection.json` is not present in the npm package folder and when schematics search for `collection.json` file it fails.

```
Collection "@candiman/website" cannot be resolved.
Error: Collection "@candiman/website" cannot be resolved.
    at NodeModulesEngineHost._resolveCollectionPath (/Users/aniruddh/aniruddh/develop/experiment/schematics-exp/sche-ex1/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/node-module-engine-host.js:91:15)
    at NodeModulesEngineHost.createCollectionDescription (/Users/aniruddh/aniruddh/develop/experiment/schematics-exp/sche-ex1/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/file-system-engine-host-base.js:111:27)
    at SchematicEngine._createCollectionDescription (/Users/aniruddh/aniruddh/develop/experiment/schematics-exp/sche-ex1/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:147:40)
    at SchematicEngine.createCollection (/Users/aniruddh/aniruddh/develop/experiment/schematics-exp/sche-ex1/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:140:43)
    at AddCommand.getCollection (/Users/aniruddh/aniruddh/develop/experiment/schematics-exp/sche-ex1/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/schematic-command.js:123:35)
    at AddCommand.runSchematic (/Users/aniruddh/aniruddh/develop/experiment/schematics-exp/sche-ex1/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/schematic-command.js:262:50)
    at AddCommand.executeSchematic (/Users/aniruddh/aniruddh/develop/experiment/schematics-exp/sche-ex1/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/add-impl.js:134:31)
    at AddCommand.run (/Users/aniruddh/aniruddh/develop/experiment/schematics-exp/sche-ex1/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/add-impl.js:105:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

`@candiman/website@0.0.5-beta.3` with schematics is available in `npm` now, if anyone wants to give a try.

The source code of the angular library can be found at [project source which publishes npm package with schematics](https://github.com/aniruddhadas9/candifood-ui/tree/develop/projects/candiman/website/src)

Comment: The question isn't named _Collection "@candiman/website" cannot be resolved_. Are you sure you're looking at the right question?

Comment: Ohh, I will change it.

Comment: Can I have a look at your source code? You haven't added any links to your source code, or to a website on your package.

Comment: this is the code https://github.com/aniruddhadas9/candifood-ui/tree/develop/projects/candiman/website/src

Comment: @Edric updating the questions as well

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `package.json` file of the dependency that you have stated does not have the `schematics` property that is a path to the schematics definition file (a JSON file):

```json
{
  "name": "@candiman/website",
  "version": "0.0.5",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.1.0-9",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.0-11",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-8",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-8",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "5.1.0-8",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "main": "bundles/candiman-website.umd.js",
  "module": "fesm5/candiman-website.js",
  "es2015": "fesm2015/candiman-website.js",
  "esm5": "esm5/candiman-website.js",
  "esm2015": "esm2015/candiman-website.js",
  "fesm5": "fesm5/candiman-website.js",
  "fesm2015": "fesm2015/candiman-website.js",
  "typings": "candiman-website.d.ts",
  "metadata": "candiman-website.metadata.json",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^1.9.0"
  }
}
```

See your package's [`package.json` file (on Unpkg)](https://unpkg.com/@candiman/website@0.0.5//package.json) for more info.

See below for an example on how your package's schematics should be declared:

```json
{
  "name": "@candiman/website",
  "version": "0.0.5",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.1.0-9",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.0-11",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-8",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-8",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "5.1.0-8",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "schematics": "./path/to/schematics.json",
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^1.9.0"
  }
}
```

Which would result in something like this when running `ng build project-name --prod`:

```json
{
  "name": "@candiman/website",
  "version": "0.0.5",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.1.0-9",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.0-11",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-8",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-8",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "5.1.0-8",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "schematics": "./path/to/schematics.json",
  "main": "bundles/candiman-website.umd.js",
  "module": "fesm5/candiman-website.js",
  "es2015": "fesm2015/candiman-website.js",
  "esm5": "esm5/candiman-website.js",
  "esm2015": "esm2015/candiman-website.js",
  "fesm5": "fesm5/candiman-website.js",
  "fesm2015": "fesm2015/candiman-website.js",
  "typings": "candiman-website.d.ts",
  "metadata": "candiman-website.metadata.json",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^1.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is `collection.json` not published as part of the package as `ng-packeger` does not include json file. Not sure though.

Comment: You're supposed to have some way of automatically copying the necessary schematics-related files to the dist folder of your package as `ng-packagr` currently doesn't do that for you (although there's currently an issue about this topic: https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/1180)

Comment: I think that is not a problem. my package.json holds the link to the collection.json but the physical collection.json is not present in the npm package folder as ng-packager does not compile/move json file. please try `@candiman/website@0.0.5-beta.3`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem following the example from this link.
https://angular.io/guide/schematics-for-libraries#building-your-schematics

The copy:collection script in the library's project root folder shows this:
`"copy:collection": "cp schematics/collection.json ../../dist/my-lib/schematics/collection.json"`
which creates an unecessary subfolder named collection.json

I changed this script to
`"copy:collection": "cp schematics/collection.json ../../dist/my-lib/schematics"`
and it copies the collection.json file into the schematics folder where it can be found.